# Rails Convention for Sharing Resources Among Many Users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, concurrency, locking, multi-user

In my app I have Users who will perform CRUD actions on Patient Record resources. Normally, after a Patient Record is created, it will just be read by the Users. However in the rare case that two (or more) Users decide that for whatever reason they want to edit that shared resource, what is the best way to resolve this?

I have been reading about optimistic and pessimistic locking, but what is still unclear to me is whether this applies just to the update action, or does locking occur every time someone tries to read a resource as well?

What I was thinking about was if there was a way in rails to see when two or more Users are on the same page, thereby notifying the second User to come to the edit page that another User is already using this resource, and therefore just wait for the first User to finish before proceeding.

How would you approach this? Thanks!

Comment: You do not mention your database, but for postgresql: "Row-level locks do not affect data querying; they block only writers to the same row."

Comment: Is this true for both optimistic and pessimistic locking?

Comment: Yes. But note, reading a locked record can be misleading, since the user may be reading data that is subsequently changed by another user after the lock is released. Postgresql has the notion of "Repeatable Read" to prevent this, but you would be writing pure sql to accomplish that, since I am not sure that ActiveRecord supports this for postgresql. Developing database apps that perform well against concurrency standards are non-trivial.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [acts_as_lockable_by](https://github.com/tareksamni/acts_as_lockable_by) gem.

Following the example in your question:

```
class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_lockable_by :id, ttl: 30.seconds
end
```

Then you can do this in your controller:

```
class PatientsController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    if patient.lock(current_user.id) 
      # It will be locked for 30 seconds for the current user
      # You will need to renew the lock by calling /patients/:id/renew_lock
    else
      # Could not lock the patient record which means it is already locked by another user
    end
  end

  def renew_lock
    if patient.renew_lock(current_user.id)
      # lock renewed return 200
    else
      # could not renew the lock, it might be already released
    end
  end

  private

  def patient
    @patient ||= Patient.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```